# material-ui-chip-input with floating input label

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, label

I have installed material-ui-chip-input for using tags on one of my input fields. I wanted a label with it so I have used material ui default label which they use for other inputs. But The input needs to be shrink when user click on that.

I am attaching my code below and the screenshot of the design. Please feel free to help. Thanks in advance!

[image]

```html
<div className={`${styles.input_range} form_design`}>
    <label className={styles.character_limit}>(13/30)</label>
    <label class="MuiFormLabel-root MuiInputLabel-root MuiInputLabel-formControl MuiInputLabel-animated" data-shrink="false" for="standard-basic" id="standard-basic-label">Title</label>
    <ChipInput
    defaultValue={['Science', 'Arts']}
    // onChange={(chips) => handleChange(chips)}
    />
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a codesanbox with your example to help you with ?

Comment: I have already attached the code I am using from material ui and haven't use CSS for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove your custom `label` and add in `ChipInput` the property `label="Title"` and you will have the result you want.

For the second `label` I have added in property `helperText`.I have added a `className` to the component, and then I will make some customizations with CSS.

```
<div className={`${styles.input_range} form_design`}>
    <ChipInput
    className="customChipInput"
    label="Title"
    helperText="(13/30)"
    defaultValue={['Science', 'Arts']}
    // onChange={(chips) => handleChange(chips)}
    />
</div>
```

In CSS you can add the below

```
.customChipInput p {
  width: fit-content;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 30px;
  right: 0;
}
```

You can check my snippet [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/xenodochial-lamport-30491?file=/src/App.js)

For more information about the component properties you can take a look [here](https://github.com/TeamWertarbyte/material-ui-chip-input#readme)

[image]